# How to compile react source code which calls a function defined in a dynamically loaded script

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please help me dynamically loading scripts into React(create-react-app).

Currently none from google search answers how to fix compile errors e.g like:

'TEST_SCRIPT' is not defined  no-undef,

where 'TEST_SCRIPT' is a variable defined in a script file which haven't been loaded yet at the compile time.

I followed the instruction in the page: https://usehooks.com/useScript/
And I checked similar answers for dynamically loading external javascripts then calling functions defined in them.

```
//dynamically loaded script

const TEST_SCRIPT = {
  start: () => {
    return 'Hello World';
  }
};
```

```
//React source code 

return(
...
<div>
  Script function call response: <b>{TEST_SCRIPT.start()}</b>
</div>
...
)
```

I expect I can compile the code with your help.
And I expect for the part, {TEST_SCRIPT.start()}, 
it displays "Hello World" after onLoaded.

Comment: That tutorial is using the TEST_SCRIPT as an example of the script that was loaded dynamically. For local files you can require/import them. Effectively the tutorial is showing you how to lazy-load code.

Comment: Mr Sullivan, does your comment imply I can solve this problem by using require/import? If yes, could you help me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue, following the example @ https://usehooks.com/useScript/ .

In my project I split the `useScript` function into another file, `use-script.js`.  This required the additional statement of `export default` before the function....

```
export default function useScript(src) {
  // Keep track of script status ("idle", "loading", "ready", "error")
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(src ? "loading" : "idle");

  useEffect(
    () => {
      // Allow falsy src value if waiting on other data needed for
      // constructing the script URL passed to this hook.
      if (!src) {
        setStatus("idle");
        return;
      }
...
```

You can see a similar set up of this recipe in the codesandbox of this example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/pm28k14qlj?file=/src/use-script.js:46-443

Good luck!

Comment: This doesn't seem to help at all. I am using intellij, have the project setup exactly like that in code-sandbox but always get  'TEST_SCRIPT' is not defined  no-undef